# Android Application Keeps Crashing at XMl parsing

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xmlhttprequest

My Application LogCat gives me this out put when running in Debug Mode:

I am trying to parse an XML document received from HTTPGet request (String result) result is the XML in string format. Just cant get it to put string values to test against for login.

> 02-20 19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-20
>   19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl cannot be cast to
>   android.sax.Element 02-20 19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   com.testingapp.MainActivity$startLogin.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:112)
>   02-20 19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   com.testingapp.MainActivity$startLogin.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
>   02-20 19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631) 02-20 19:39:48.326:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) 02-20
>   19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
>   02-20 19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-20
>   19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-20 19:39:48.326:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 02-20
>   19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-20
>   19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-20 19:39:48.326:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   02-20 19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 02-20
>   19:39:48.326: E/AndroidRuntime(774):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I was able to Focus the error into my onPostExecute AsyncTask:

```
@Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                int z = 0;  
                String xml = result;
                String KEY_ITEM = "Response";
                String KEY_SUCCESS = "Success";
                String KEY_FAIL = "Fail";
                String KEY_UID = "UID";

                  Document doc = getDomElement(xml);

                    if(xml != null)
                    {
                        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
                        {   
                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        String successString = getValue(e,KEY_SUCCESS);
                        String UIDString = getValue(e,KEY_UID);
                        String failString = getValue(e,KEY_FAIL);

                        if(failString.equals("Fail")){
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check username and password.", duration);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                        else{
                            if(successString.equals("Success")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Connection to Retrieve Data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }
        }
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Appears to be a ClassCastException... Can you please post your XML data?

Comment: <Login>
<Response>
<Success>Success</Success>
<userID>801</userID>
</Response>
</Login>

Comment: the above is the output from the service.

Comment: Looks like you have a bad import. you should be importing.. org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.ElementImpl  (or a related class) instead of android.sax.Element.                                                   Can you please check and confirm?

Comment: all,using:import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

Comment: i am not able to import org.apache.harmony because once you get past org.apache it gives an error.

Comment: Try replacing 'import org.w3c.dom.Node' with 'import  org.w3c.dom.Element'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24854/discussion-between-keeano-martin-and-gaurav-arora)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem...
Change this

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) { 
    NodeList n = ((Document) item).getElementsByTagName(str);
    return getElementValue(n.item(0)); 
}
```

to

```
public String getValue(Element item, String str) { 
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);  // Removed Typecast
    return getElementValue(n.item(0)); 
}
```

You are casting the Element.getElementsByTagName(str) is returning a NodeList object.
but you are casting it to a Document object, hence the Class Cast Exception.

Comment: Have been stuck on this for awhile and this helped out so much, thanks!!